# Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I copy part of the `firebase-mlkit` sample code only for Image labeling.  When I run on my `Nokia 6.1` and got the following error message:-

> type=1400 audit(0.0:4015): avc: denied { read } for     name="u:object_r:vendor_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17821 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c7,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist

I put the following permission in the **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"    />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I can run the sample `firebase-mlkit` on the Nokia 6.1 without any problem.  Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I solved it by reducing the library versions in build.gradle

Comment: @sanidhya09 Thank u so much for the hint! It was one of the firebase library that was causing the error.

Comment: Which library???

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue with Redmi 6 pro.

Comment: @SanidhyaKumar can you give your solution. I will offer immediate bounty

Comment: @RanjithKumar i reduced the library version of arcore and sceneform. If you are not using these then try finding which library in your gradle is  using camera 2 apis. I used Arcore 1.7

Comment: I'm somewhat facing the same issue where im using some android camera library (background camera), and im running it as a service through work manager class periodically, the app works for first few hours but then later makes my entire device hang, and i see the log to find this error, so I removed firebase also from my app, still facing the error, so any solutions for this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588357/15443504) solution may be help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" as a public default prop like:

```
vendor.camera.aux.packagelist u:object_r:exported2_default_prop:s0 exact string
```

in file([AOSP_DIR]/system/sepolicy/public/property_contexts)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the root cause of this issue but I was able to solve this issue by delaying to start camera preview in my App.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

> Don't forget to stop preview and release camera onPause event of
>   activity.