# Getting Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" ERROR unsing Flashlight

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-permissions, flashlight

In my application I am using the Smartphone's flash light when a Notification arrives. When a new Push notification arrives the following function gets executed.

```
    private static void flashlight(final Context context, final String userId) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                    if (cameraManager != null) {
                        String cameraId  = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                        if (cameraId != null) {
                            for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                            }
                            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("PushCreator_flashlight", e.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

I also have the permissions in the Manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

It's working but the only problem I have is that the following Error is thrown the entire time the flash light gets used.

[image]

I already checked out the following question but it did not work:
[Access denied for property “vendor.camera.aux.packagelist”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990262/access-denied-for-property-vendor-camera-aux-packagelist)

Does somebody know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. Our team is trying to open camera via WebView and it's not able to open. Showing the same error message you posted above? Did you figure out a solution for your problem?

Comment: Hey unfortunately i was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet and just ignored it because it works.