# Getting flutter warning "Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-camera

I have been getting this flutter warning "Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" anytime i am trying use a flutter package to turn on flashlight .

This is from my AndroidManifest file .

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

I followed the other solutions but nothing seemed to work . Do you guys have a solution to this .

Comment: Hey @Sovit are you using latest version of flutter sdk?

Comment: i am using Flutter 3.0.5 .

Comment: your issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990262/access-denied-for-property-vendor-camera-aux-packagelist please check out

Comment: if your project is old and sdk is new , try creating a new project and pass on the lib folder and change other native configurations whatever required.

Comment: Hey @pavankumarv i did this but still get the error . I created a new project and updated everything but still got the error . Also This error comes only when I am trying to access the flashlight but my camera works fine , thats strange .

Comment: hey @Sovit I researched this issue, this issue seems to be device specific, update the emulator details (device, android version)

Comment: try running on lower version , do some tweaks on this, give a try.

Comment: Hey , I am running it on a real device one plus Nord CE .